# How to put a TextView under an ExpandableListView and make the ExpandableListView to fill the remaining space screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the `ExpandableListView` to fill the screen and I want to out the inner `RelativeLayout` below the `ExpandableListView`, but the `ExpandableListView` will fill the whole screen and I can't see the `RelativeLayout`.

What am I doing wrong?

I have this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/all_pages_padding_top"
    tools:context="driver.mci.ir.mcicardriver.activity.MessagesActivity">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/messagesListView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top">
    </ExpandableListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messagesListView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/login_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/login_icon_size"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sendmessage"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What if you use `scrollView` ?

Comment: i dont want to scroll anything. it shouldnt

Comment: Do You want expandable list view should be first element and the second relative layout which contains the image button  and text should be at the bottom as second child ? @MahboobehMohammadi

Answer (score 1):

Try this **optimized** layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/all_pages_padding_top"
    tools:context="driver.mci.ir.mcicardriver.activity.MessagesActivity"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/login_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_icon_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/sendmessage"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    />
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/messagesListView"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's **flatter** (I got you rid of the extra nested layout). Therefore, **more performant**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Remove the ** in the layout I just used to highlight the lines

Quite not sure anybody can edit this comment to improve:

You gave the height for ExpandableListView as android:layout_height="match_parent" and after u r trying to put a layout with property below so its already taken the full height. But here I gave the bottom layout has to be the Relative layout the ExpandableListView has to come above the relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/all_pages_padding_top"
tools:context="driver.mci.ir.mcicardriver.activity.MessagesActivity">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/messagesListView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
     **android:layout_above="@+id/textLayout"**
    android:layout_gravity="right|top">
</ExpandableListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
   **android:id="@+id/textLayout"**
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/login_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_icon_size"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/sendmessage"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works, Thank you. but i don't get it whats the difference between using `android:layout_above`  and `android:layout_below`?

Comment: @MahboobehMohammadi I've updated the answer u can check

Comment: `whats the difference between using android:layout_above and android:layout_below?` *above* means *on top of* (so, *before*, in a vertical direction). *below* is the opposite (so, *under*).